# Java - Reading URL Response

Tags: java

I want to grab the source code of a page which contains the word "true" or "false". That's the only two words that would be on that page, no other formatting.

So I just need Java to URL connect to that page "http://example.com/example.php" and just grab the contents.

Comment: Do you mean "download content by url into a Java class"?

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Yeah, pretty much. Basically getting a page's content using the URL class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this tutorial :  [Java URL example - Download the contents of a URL](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010011)

Comment: Thanks so much for the find. I was searching for hours on google so I guess I was using the wrong keywords. Not sure if I'll succeed in following the tutorial though, since I'm new to Java.

Comment: @Fallen Angel - If it's really what you need, remember to click the outlined "checkmark" next to this answer to accept it as the most appropriate answer for you question.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask if you fail to find a good solution to one specific part, though. We still beginner in the end!

Comment: @Jared Farrish - I want to click it lol but it said I have to wait 8 minutes xD

Comment: That's to discourage spammers and malcontents.

Comment: Thanks for all the help you guys gave. I think I got it working.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to do that using Apache Commons IO. For example for mentioned action you can just write

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/example.php");
String content = IOUtils.toString(new InputStreamReader(
                        url.openStream()));
```

Comment: Eclipse asks to create a new class "IOUtils" !!
So google gives me the class at http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/commons-io-1.0/src/java/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java.shtml 
Creating this class make Eclipse asks again for a new class "CopyUtils" !!!

Comment: You have to download commons-io-2.0.1.jar from http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi and include it in the classpath. No need for creating new classes.